# VB6.0 compatible control that will work on Win 7 for SSL3 communication

Tags: windows-7, ssl, vb6

Our VB6 application uses a 3rd party control (PowerTCP from Dart) for SSL3 connectivity. However, this doesn't seem to work on Windows 7 - and I have not found any useful information on what I can do to make it work.

Is there a VB6.0 compatible control that will work on Win 7 for SSL3 communication?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can only suggest a workaround, not a solution: If you do not find a suitable ActiveX control for your VB6 application, you might consider migrating the communication part of your application to VB.NET.

This has the following advantages:

- [Calling .net code from VB6 is not hard.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248)
- The .net Framework has a built-in [SSLStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) class, which might already do what you want, so you're not dependent on a third-party component.
- Since [VB6 IDE support ended in April 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx), you will probably want to migrate your application to VB.NET sooner or later anyway. Therefore, migrating parts of your application now might be a better investment of your time than familiarizing yourself with a new third-party ActiveX control.

It has the following disadvantages:

- One more layer in your application: Your VB6 code can call the .net code, but not vice-versa.
- You need to familiarize yourself with the .net-COM interop stuff (it's not difficult, but it's something that needs to be done).
- Your deployment process becomes more complicated, since you require the .net Framework to be installed on your customer's machines and you need to register your .net library as a COM component (so that your VB6 application can access it).

Answer (score 0):

Dart still support the ActiveX control - why not [ask them for help directly](http://www.dart.com/support.aspx) and post a question on their [support forum](http://support.dart.com/)?

Apologies in advance if you've already tried this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - however, we are looking for an alternative to Dart.